# Is it a good idea to use NodeJS terminal or iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis, forever, iisnode

I have micorosoft windows server 2012 r2 and I have nodejs as web and api server and I want to deply it in production mode. But my question is should i install forever npm module and set to production mode and run via command prompt and may be write .bat file to execute on start up or iisnode is a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that iisnode is a better idea.
Host using IIS is better than let a nodejs prompt always opened, running your server, with a danger of someone close or do something that you don't want.
I always use iisnode and is very simple, look at [Github page](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode).

Comment: Thank you. Will use iisnode.

Comment: I would say either. I would recommend using a process manager for this one, like forever, pm2, nodemon, and drop the iisnode, as that technology is out of support these days.